# Prevent iOS body scrolling when overlay is visible and scrollable. No jQuery or External Libraries

Tags: javascript, ios, css, scroll, mobile-safari

I have a page with a typical  tag content inside and a "footer" element. 
This footer element opens to be a full page overlay when touched. The footer's size is set to the window height, but the contents of the footer is typically longer and will scroll.

At this point I have the contents of the footer css set to

```css
footer {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  position:fixed;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  height: (set to window height inline);
}
```

The body is set to the css below only when the footer is expanded.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Testing in Chrome and Safari on a desktop work fine and the footer content scrolls. When tested in iOS Safari the content scrolls fine sometimes, unless you touch and hold, then move. It grabs the  and scrolls behind the expanded footer.

I have been racking my head on this and tried a ton of solutions I have read with no avail.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A screenshot of your problem would help to understand your problem. Also, do you really need `position: fixed;` or would `position: absolute;` work out as well. Mobile browsers have problems with fixed positioning.

Comment: @kleinfreund I don't think a screenshot would make a difference. It would be difficult to show. Are you referring to fixed under the body or the footer?